# What are the purposes of different libraries present under cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs folder?

Tags: android, llvm, abi, libunwind

In android ndk, under folder sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi-v7a, I can see these following libraries.

1. libandroid_support.a
2. libc++.so
3. libc++_shared.so
4. libc++abi.a
5. libunwind.a

Could you please explain what is the purpose of each one. If there is any dependencies among these, please explain.